# UIPageControl (Page Control) not show in UIPageViewController

Tags: cocoa-touch, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

my `UIPageViewController` class conforms to `UIPageViewControllerDataSource` protocol and yet `UIPageControl` is not visible.

I've attached screen representing segues between `UIPageViewController` and it's child `UIViewController`'s which are added by `setViewControllers` method.

[image]

Question is why Page Control is not shown and what can i do with it except adding `UIPageControl` instance to view myself ?

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, it seems as though UIPageControl only appears when the Transition Style is set to "Scroll" -- very frustrating! (Hope I'm wrong?)
Click on your UIPageViewController ('Home Page View Controller'?) to see the option under Page View Controller.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've implemented the optional `-presentationCountForPageViewController:` and `-presentationIndexForPageViewController:` data source methods.

UIPageViewController.h is very clear about the requirements:

> A page indicator will be visible if both methods are implemented,
>   transition style is '`UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll`', and
>   navigation orientation is
>   '`UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal`'.